# Paging on Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a main view with a partial view.
The partial view allows paging, I am using Bootstrap.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Main()
{
    return View();
}

//[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _Partial(int page)
{
    Model = //returns records for requested page
    return View(Model);
}
```

View:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= model.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "_Partial", new { page = i, })</li> }
    }
</ul>
```

My problem is, although the paging works, selecting a page is calling the _Partial Action directly ( after I removed `[ChildActionOnly]`
So on paging it loads the Partial View only without the Main View which it forms part of...therefor it is missing the 'frame' provided by the Main View or any formatting.

Should I be following a different approach or is there a way to call a Partial Action and it’s Main Action?

I guess I would have liked to do something like…

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Main + _Partial", new { page = i, })</li>
```

Or how can I get Bootstrap Paging (I don't want to go the Ajax route) to work on a Partial View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use ajax, then you have to return the whole page. Here an example for your case:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Main()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult SomeAction(int page) //Name this as your like
{
    // I use viewbag here for convenience, 
    //you should consider to create new view model if necessary.
    ViewBag.PageNum = page;

    return View();
}

//[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _Partial(int page)
{
    Model = //returns records for requested page
    return View(Model);
}
```

View "SomeAction.cshtml":

```
@*Put your Main page content here*@

@Html.Action("SomeAction", "YourControllerName", new { page = ViewBag.PageNum })

@*Put your Main page content here*@
```

And Your pagination should change to:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= model.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "SomeAction", new { page = i, })</li> }
    }
</ul>
```

Keep in mind that I created the "SomeAction" only because I don't know what exactly does your "Main" action do. If the "Main" is simply the 1st page, then you should merge the "SomeAction" and "Main" into one:

```
public ActionResult Main(int page = 1)
{
    ViewBag.PageNum = page;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You are correct; I shouldn't be calling the Partial Action. I misunderstood my own problem at first. 
I have a Main view with 3 Bootstrap Tabs, each tab have a partial view. And each tab has paging. The problem is when I change a page on tab 2 then the Main View will be loaded and it won't realize that tab 2 should be the active tab. I guess I am going to need some Java to do that, but I'll post a separate question. I've marked your answer as correct since it does answer the original question posted.